# Casting to struct type created with typedef

Tags: c++, casting

I have casting problem with structures in my C++ code. I use C-style casting. But if i try to cast using alternative name (created using `typedef`) i have an error. Please, look at my code.

```
class T
{
public:
    typedef struct kIdS* kIdN;
    typedef struct kIdS {
        int* a;
        double* b;
    }  kIdR;

    typedef struct tIdS {
        int* a;
        double* b;
        float* c;
    }  tIdR;

    int a;
    double b;
    float c;

    void F()
    {
        a = 0; 
        b = 0; 
        c = 0;
        struct kIdS A = {&a, &b};
        struct tIdS B = {&a, &b, &c};
        struct kIdS* knv[] = {&A, (struct kIdS*)&B};
        struct kIdS* knv1[] = {&A, (kIdN)&B}; //error
    }
};
```

The error is:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'T::kIdN' to 'T::kIdS *'
    Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, 
    C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Why i can not use alternative name? How i can solve this problem using alternative name created by `typedef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is in first `typedef struct kIdS* kIdN` you have no struct in your class that named `kIdS`, so C++ compiler think that you are talking about a global `struct kIdS` and then `typedef` that global struct to `kIdN` and in line `struct kIdS* knv1[] = {&A, (kIdN)&B};` error is obvious, global `struct kIdS*` can't be used instead of `T::kIdS*`, but I have a question from you, why you use `struct X` while you can simply say `X`??

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right about global struct. The solution is place struct definition before typedef. Now compiler knows that struct is local. Now i know that instead struct X we can use simply X. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use inheritance?

```
struct tIdS : public kIdS { ... }
```

Comment: Because i perform integration pure C-code with C++ code with minimal changes. Using inheritance i will have another problems.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of excessive typedef's.

```
struct kIdS {
    int* a;
    double* b;
};

typedef kIdS* kIdN;
typedef kIdS kIdR;

.....

kIdS* knv[] = {&A, (kIdS*)&B};
kIdS* knv1[] = {&A, (kIdN)&B};
```